# error on remote connection to mysql

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I ve been trying to connect my dedicated server mysql db from my computers localhost
my code is here;

```
$dbhost = 'domain.com';
$dbuser = 'username';
$dbpass = 'pass';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

$dbname = 'dbname';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

I get that error

```
Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 61
```

Dedicated server is Linux centos 64 bit, php 3.2.4, mysql 5.1.54

Is there any workaround that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that MySQL is running and if you are able to connect by using 'telnet x.x.x.x 3306'. If you can get that far, your problem exists in MySQL's permissions. If not, check the firewall (iptables -L) as the previous person suggested, and verify that my.cnf is set up to listen to tcp (make sure there is no skip_networking line).

Answer (score 0):

Check the my.cnf on your MySQL server, specially the bind-address parameter. Most of the time you need it commented to accept connections on all IP addresses of the server.

Comment: i tried both, didnt work. on /etc/my.cnf file.

Comment: @Ahmet vardar: Did you restart MySQL ?

Comment: yes of course i did

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall settings on your dedicated server. 
Maybe the port for the MySql server is blocked (usally 3306).